# Register user acces in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a login in laravel 5 and I need to register in a table the user information when entering the site (ip address, os, browser and timestamp) i have the code and my model to register this. 
I have a middelware for this login but when use the function 'handle' this save a record when refresh the browser

Thanks

This is my code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if(!Auth::guard('web_admin')->check()){
        return redirect('admin/login');
    }
    if(Auth::guard('web_admin')->user()->delete==='0' && Auth::guard('web_admin')->user()->status==='1'){
        $browser_data = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],true);
        //dd($browser_data);
        dd($request);
        $model = new Access();
        $model->ip = $request->ip();
        $model->dir_mac = $this->mac() ;
        $model->computer = gethostname()."/".$this->operating_system_detection();
        $model->browser= $this->navegador();
        $model->admin_id =Auth::guard('web_admin')->user()->id;
        $model->save();
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        Auth::guard('web_admin')->logout();
        return redirect('admin/login');
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont undertand , update the question whit my code

Comment: what is you question, btw?

Comment: How can I make a historical record of user income?

Comment: You say you have your model which saves it, you say you have your middleware, so now, what if your actual question or problem? This is very unclear.

Comment: @JorgeOmarTovarMartínez This would probably be way easier if you just edit the existing controller.

Answer (score 0):

When the user login information will be recorded. As a result, use a function after validation and before moving to the home page to receive and store this information. Because the user will try to log in once.